# decide if two names are brothers or not

Tags: java, string, loops, coding-style

The problem is :

> Write a program that read form user 2 full names, and then decide if the 2 are brothers or not.
>
> Sample Run:
>
> Enter 2 names:
>
> ```
> - First name:  Ali Ibrahim Mohammed
> - Second name: Ahmad Ibrahim Mohammed
> ```
>
> `Ali and Ahmad are brothers`

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{
static Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

   public static void main(String args[])
    {
String name1 = ""; //the name1 without first name
String name2 = ""; //the name2 without first name

String firstname1="";//only the first name of name1
String firstname2="" ;//only the fist name of name2

String fname ="";
String lname ="";

String string, string2;

int space ;
int i =0;
 int j=0;

System.out.println("Enter 2 names :");
while ( i<2 )
{
if (i==0)
    System.out.println("- First name :"); 
    else
        System.out.println("- Second name :"); 
        
  while (j==i)
   {
    string = scan.nextLine();
     
    space= string.indexOf(" ");
    fname = string.substring(0,space);
      
    string2 = string.toLowerCase();  
    lname = string.substring(space);
     
    string2 = lname.toLowerCase(); 
    j++;

  }
     if(i==0){
     firstname1=fname;
     lname=name1;
     }
     
     else if(i==1){
     firstname2=fname;
     lname=name2;
     }
     
    i++;
}

if ( name1.equals(name2))
System.out.println(firstname1 + " and " + firstname2 + " are brothers ");
else 
System.out.println(firstname1 + " and " + firstname2 + " are NOT brothers ");


}
}
```

I tried to write my code, but they are always brothers even if the last name is not the same!

Comment: Have you used a debugger to spot the problems in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to split your problem into smaller problems, and code each.  For example,

1. How should you represent a person's name?  Does everyone have a first, middle, and last name? What happens if someone types just *George Booth*?
2. Can you write a `Name` class?
3. What would be a better set of variable names?
4. How would you test your code?

Also, try not to do everything in `main`. It makes things hard to test.

Comment: but I am still a beginner , I am not allowed to use several main(s) ... thank anyway

Comment: No, I meant methods other than `main`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want

```
if ( lname1.equals(lname2))
```

instead of

```
if ( name1.equals(name2))
```

There may be other problems, but this is at least one of them.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented this using a tokenizer, with this approach the program is able to find if multiple people are brothers. How this works is we store the person full name in an ArrayList. We then break up those name using a tokenizer and store only the lastname into a new array. We then check for everybody that have the same last name and display that they are brothers.

```
   List<String> names = new ArrayList <String>();

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    //gets user name
    for (int x = 0; x < 4; x++)
    {
        System.out.printf("Enter Full Name #%d: ", (x + 1));
        names.add(scanner.nextLine());
    }
    String [] lastName = new String [names.size()];

    //gets lastName
    for (int x = 0; x < names.size(); x++)
    {
        StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(names.get(x));
        while (token.hasMoreTokens())
                lastName[x] = token.nextToken();
    }

    //check for brothers
    for (int x = 0; x < names.size(); x++)
        for (int i = x + 1; i < names.size();i++)
        {
            if (lastName[x].equalsIgnoreCase(lastName[i]))
                System.out.printf("%s and %s are brothers",names.get(x),names.get(i));
        }
```

Output:

```
 Enter Full Name #1: Andree Freemantle
 Enter Full Name #2: Mario Dennis
 Enter Full Name #3: Kyle Freemantle
 Enter Full Name #4: Steve dennis
 Andree Freemantle and Kyle Freemantle are brothers 
 Mario Dennis and Steve dennis are brother
```

Comment: [Note] this could be broken down further into smaller methods

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to below modified version your code, hope this solves your issue.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String n1="Ali Ibrahim Mohammed";
  String n2="Ahmad Ibrahim Mohammed";

  String name1FirstName=n1.split(" ")[0]; 
  String name2FirstName=n2.split(" ")[0];

  String name1LastName=n1.split(" ")[2]; 
  String name2LastName=n2.split(" ")[2];

  String name1MiddleName=n1.split(" ")[1]; 
  String name2MiddleName=n2.split(" ")[1];

  if(name1LastName.equals(name2LastName)){ // Check if Last name is same or not

      if(name1MiddleName.equals(name2MiddleName)){ // Check if middle name is same or not
          System.out.println(name1FirstName+"  and "+name2FirstName+" are brothers");
      }else{
          System.out.println(name1FirstName+"  and "+name2FirstName+" are not brothers");
      }



  }else{
      System.out.println(name1FirstName+"  and "+name2FirstName+" are not brothers");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import java.util.*;

     class Test
    {
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

       public static void main(String args[])
        {
    //String name1 = ""; //the name1 without first name
    //String name2 = ""; //the name2 without first name

    String firstname1="";//only the first name of name1
    String firstname2="" ;//only the fist name of name2

    String fname ="";
    String lname ="";
    String lname1 ="";
    String lname2 ="";

    String string, string2;

    int space ;
    int i =0;
     int j=0;

    System.out.println("Enter 2 names :");
    while ( i<2 )
    {
    if (i==0)
        System.out.println("- First name :"); 
        else
            System.out.println("- Second name :"); 

      while (j==i)
       {
        string = scan.nextLine();

        space= string.indexOf(" ");
        fname = string.substring(0,space);

        string2 = string.toLowerCase();  
        lname = string.substring(space);

        string2 = lname.toLowerCase(); 
        j++;

      }
         if(i==0){
         firstname1=fname;
         lname1=lname;
         }

         else if(i==1){
         firstname2=fname;
         lname2=lname;
         }

        i++;
    }

    if ( lname1.equals(lname2))
    System.out.println(firstname1 + " and " + firstname2 + " are brothers ");
    else 
    System.out.println(firstname1 + " and " + firstname2 + " are NOT brothers ");


    }
    }
```

output:--

```
    Enter 2 names :
    - First name :
    Ali Ibrahim Mohammed
    - Second name :
    Ahmad Ibrahim Mohammed
    Ali and Ahmad are brothers 

retry:==

    Enter 2 names :
    - First name :
    Ahmad Ibrahim 
    - Second name :
    Ali Ibrahim Mohammed]
    Ahmad and Ali are NOT brothers
```